# Сайт рухнул после подключения инстаграма к сервису массфола. Проблема Токен

Tags: html

Ребята помогите! Упал сайт после того как подключил инстаграм (где была ссылка на сайт) к внешнему сервису расскрутки инстаграма. Разработчик говорит что пропал/изменился токен. Что это такое и как это можно решить? спасибо
[image: пропал токен]

Comment: Вместо скриншота лучше указывать код и логи текстом в содержании вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Получи новый токен и постав вместо старова (http://www.socialnetworkingtools.com.ua/reg-token)- не реклама